# How to check if this algorithm may not terminate?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Let x denote a vector of p values (i.e. a data point in p dimensional space).

I have two sets: set A of n elements A = {xi, .., xn} and a set B of m elements B = {xj, .., xm}, where |A| > 1 and |B| > 1. Given an integer k > 0, let dist(x, k, A) a function which returns the mean Euclidean distance from x to its k nearest points in A; and dist(x, k, B) the mean Euclidean distance from x to its k nearest points in B.

I have the following algorithm:

```
Repeat
{
   A' = { x in A, such that dist(x, k, A) > dist(x, k, B) }
   B' = { x in B, such that dist(x, k, A) < dist(x, k, B) }
   A = { x in A such that x not in A' } U B'
   B = { x in B such that x not in B' } U A'
}
Until CONDITION == True
```

**Termination:** CONDITION is True when no more elements move from A to B or from B to A (that is A' and B' becomes empty), or when |A| or |B| becomes less than or equals to 1.

1) Is it possible to prove that this algorithm terminates ?

2) And if so, is it also possible to have an upper bound for the number of iterations required to terminate ?

**Note:** the k nearest points to x in a set S, means: the k points (others than x) in S, having the smallest Euclidean distance to x.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematic. Try http://mathoverflow.net/ instead

Comment: Seems like a job for induction. No time to think about it right now though :)

Comment: It is not clear what `{ xi in A, such that dist(x, k, A) > dist(x, k, B) }` means. The predicate after `such that` is either a constant true or a constant false, as it does not mention `xi`. Consequently, your `A'` is either `A` or the empty set.

Comment: @n.m. well it is x instead of xi. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this algorithm can loop forever, oscillating between two or more states. I determined this experimentally using the following Python program:

```
def mean(seq):
    if len(seq) == 0:
        raise IndexError("didn't expect empty sequence for mean")
    return sum(seq) / float(len(seq))

def dist(a,b):
    return abs(a-b)

def mean_dist(x, k, a):
    neighbors = {p for p in a if p != x}
    neighbors = sorted(neighbors, key=lambda p: dist(p,x))
    return mean([dist(x, p) for p in neighbors[:k]])

def frob(a,b,k, verbose = False):
    def show(msg):
        if verbose:
            print msg
    seen_pairs = set()
    iterations = 0
    while True:
        iterations += 1
        show("Iteration #{}".format(iterations))
        a_star = {x for x in a if mean_dist(x, k, a) > mean_dist(x,k,b)}
        b_star = {x for x in b if mean_dist(x, k, a) < mean_dist(x,k,b)}
        a_temp = {x for x in a if x not in a_star} | b_star
        b_temp = {x for x in b if x not in b_star} | a_star
        show("\tA`: {}".format(list(a_star)))
        show("\tB`: {}".format(list(b_star)))
        show("\tA becomes {}".format(list(a_temp)))
        show("\tB becomes {}".format(list(b_temp)))
        if a_temp == a and b_temp == b:
            return a, b
        key = (tuple(sorted(a_temp)), tuple(sorted(b_temp)))
        if key in seen_pairs:
            raise Exception("Infinite loop for values {} and {}".format(list(a_temp),list(b_temp)))
        seen_pairs.add(key)
        a = a_temp
        b = b_temp

import random
#creates a set of random integers, with the given number of elements.
def randSet(size):
    a = set()
    while len(a) < size:
        a.add(random.randint(0, 10))
    return a

size = 2
k = 1
#p equals one because I don't feel like doing vector math today

while True:
    a = randSet(size)
    b = randSet(size)
    try:
        frob(a,b, k)
    except IndexError as e:
        continue
    except Exception as e:
        print "infinite loop detected for initial inputs {} and {}".format(list(a), list(b))
        #run the algorithm again, but showing our work this time
        try:
            frob(a,b,k, True)
        except:
            pass
        break
```

Result:

```
infinite loop detected for initial inputs [10, 4] and [1, 5]
Iteration #1
        A`: [10, 4]
        B`: [1, 5]
        A becomes [1, 5]
        B becomes [10, 4]
Iteration #2
        A`: [1, 5]
        B`: [10, 4]
        A becomes [10, 4]
        B becomes [1, 5]
Iteration #3
        A`: [10, 4]
        B`: [1, 5]
        A becomes [1, 5]
        B becomes [10, 4]
```

In this case, the loop never terminates because A and B continually switch entirely. While experimenting with larger set sizes, I found a case where only some elements switch:

```
infinite loop detected for initial inputs [8, 1, 0] and [9, 4, 5]
Iteration #1
        A`: [8]
        B`: [9]
        A becomes [0, 1, 9]
        B becomes [8, 4, 5]
Iteration #2
        A`: [9]
        B`: [8]
        A becomes [0, 1, 8]
        B becomes [9, 4, 5]
Iteration #3
        A`: [8]
        B`: [9]
        A becomes [0, 1, 9]
        B becomes [8, 4, 5]
```

Here, elements 8 and 9 move back and forth while the other elements stay in place.

Comment: Thank you for your example. If as soon as I find an element x in A having dist(x, k, A) > dist(x, k, B) I put it in B, and as soon as I find an element x in B having dist(x, k, A) < dist(x, k, B) I put it in B, would it be the same (algorithm never stops) ?

Comment: Hard to say, unless you can rigorously define "as soon as one finds". See [here](http://pastebin.com/ABgDK3HF) for a program which implements the algorithm `Repeat{while (any element should be moved from A to B){move that element from A to B}; while (any element should be moved from B to A){move that element from B to A};} Until there is no change in A and B`. Running a few thousand random test cases, all of them eventually terminated successfully. This means one of two things: the algorithm always terminates for any input; or, I just didn't find the input that causes it to loop forever.